# php/mysql search for multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a table homes with (country,city,area,published) fields. I have a search form where someone can enter country or city or area. I want to get all homes which are published = 1 and any of the search terms matches any of their fields.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM homes 
WHERE published = 1 
AND 
LOWER(country) LIKE '$search%' 
OR 
LOWER(city) LIKE '$search%'
OR
LOWER(area) LIKE '$search%'
```

The problem is that it return homes that have published = 0...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest parentheses.

```
SELECT * FROM homes 
WHERE published = 1 
AND
(
 LOWER(country) LIKE '$search%' 
 OR 
 LOWER(city) LIKE '$search%'
 OR
 LOWER(area) LIKE '$search%'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   homes 
WHERE  published = 1 
       AND ( country LIKE '$search%' 
              OR city LIKE '$search%' 
              OR area LIKE '$search%' )
```

Like already does the case-insensitive stuff so you don't need it.

The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: My default character set is UTF-8 and collation is utf_general_ci. I think I need the LOWER()