# What is the correct MySQL syntax to retrieve data with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving data from a database with php and MySQL as follows

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE (title LIKE      '%$Search%' OR keywords LIKE '%$Search%') AND approved = 'YES' ORDER BY title ASC");
```

The query is correct and there are no errors and the query works fine for "title LIKE '%$Search%'" but the parameter "OR keywords LIKE '%$Search%'" is not retrieving data. The parameter "AND" also works correctly.

The keywords are stored in the database for example "pizza, restaurants, take away" but I don't see that is a problem.

My question is "What is the correct syntax for applying the "OR" parameter?

Comment: try removing the brackets around `(title LIKE      '%$Search%' OR keywords LIKE '%$Search%')` those are generally used for sub-queries.

Comment: Thank you Fred -ii, you are also are faster with an answer than my screen refresh rate!! I will try your suggestion now. Nope, that didn't work out - the results remain the same. The "OR" is not being read.

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted an answer below to better illustrate, including an example of a subquery, should you want to look into that.

Comment: could you provide some data???

Answer (score 2):

Remove the brackets around `(title LIKE '%$Search%' OR keywords LIKE '%$Search%')`

Those are generally used for subqueries.

```
$query = mysql_query("
                     SELECT * FROM pictures 
                     WHERE title LIKE '%$Search%' 
                     OR keywords LIKE '%$Search%' 
                     AND approved = 'YES' 
                     ORDER BY title ASC
                     ");
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Here is an example of a subquery, and pulled from the manual on MySQL.com:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);
```

---

**Edit:**

Or try a different quoting method:

```
$query = mysql_query("
                     SELECT * FROM pictures 
                     WHERE title LIKE '".%$Search%."' 
                     OR keywords LIKE '".%$Search%."' 
                     AND approved = 'YES' 
                     ORDER BY title ASC
                     ");
```

---

You could also try escaping your data:

```
$Search = mysql_real_escape_string($Search);
```

as an example. I don't know how you're assigning that variable.

---

**phpMyAdmin test edit:**

This is what I used inside phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE col1 LIKE '%pizza%' 
OR col2 LIKE '%pizza%' 
AND col3 = 'YES' 
ORDER BY col1 ASC
```

using `pizza` as the search keyword seeing that `$Search` will be based on the same keyword for you, where columns contain "large pizza" in one, and "pizza, take away, restaurants" in another.

- Remember that, whatever you're using/assigning `$Search` to, must reside inside all your queried columns.

---

You may also want to make use of `explode()`.

Here is an example pulled from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289777/

```
<?php
  $search = 'Gold Chain Shirt';
  $bits = explode(' ', $search);

  $sql = "SELECT name FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR name LIKE '%", $bits) . "%'";
```

The above will generate this query:

```
SELECT name FROM product WHERE name LIKE '%Gold%' OR name LIKE '%Chain%' OR name LIKE '%Shirt%'
```

Comment: Correct answer Fred but the "OR" parameter is still not selecting anything :(

Comment: @StrayDog You wrote *"The keywords are stored in the database for example "pizza, restaurants, take away"* - how is data stored in your table, as single words per each row, or as comma seperated and with many words in one row? Plus, give an example of what's being passed in `$Search`

Comment: @StrayDog Keep in mind that `WHERE title LIKE '%$Search%'` and `AND approved = 'YES'` must have matching data, same thing for the inverse of that, being `OR keywords LIKE '%$Search%'` and `AND approved = 'YES'`. Add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` see if it returns any errors.

Comment: Correct Fred - the keywords are stored words seperated with a comma and a space like this: "pizza, take away, restaurants, peperoni" (without the " "comments) I will try your suggestion. Tested - no error.

Comment: @StrayDog Strange; my test proved to be positive, using your data. Did you add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` to see if it returned any errors? Try putting that query in phpmyadmin and see. Might be something in your code elsewhere that is not echoing right. Something you didn't post.

Comment: The results from the database search are parsed to an XML file... your insight "Might be something in your code elsewhere that is not echoing right" may well be correct, unfortunately I have no errors anywhere... that is why I am assuming that the "OR" is not passing data... as you mention it could be that the OR parameter is correct but the error lies elsewhere... good point Fred!!

Comment: @StrayDog I've made a slight edit using different quotes, but I doubt that'll make a difference. Sometimes it does, might make a difference. Reload my answer under **Edit:**.

Comment: Tested but the results remain the same - no selection by keywords :( gotta go out to the shop before it closes... hehe I will be back shortly... your help and suggestions are excellent. :)

Comment: @StrayDog *Baffled*. Try adding a `GROUP BY` say like `GROUP BY title` - As I said, I tested different searches and all proved to be successful. Any way you can provide DB schema of your data/columns? Plus, remember, whatever you're using `$Search` for that's being passed in there, for example: `$Search = "pizza";` that word must reside inside all your queried columns. I need an example of what you are using `$Search` and how it's assigned. I'd need to see a bit more code and how you're assigning that variable.

Comment: Also baffled!! The XML file outputs the keywords and they are correctly echoed under DESCRIPTION which is echoed under TITLE. The database schema is; TITLE - varchar(255) utf8_general_ci... DESCRIPTION - text utf8_general_ci... KEYWORDS - varchar(255) utf8_general_ci.... All are correctly read and parsed to XML and the XML output is correct.... The search results by TITLE are correct.... the search results for DESCRIPTION are correct if I include it... but the results for KEYWORDS are just not there... somewhat weird!?

Comment: @StrayDog Yes, very weird. I've Google'd some, and found an example you could base yourself on. Please reload my answer and go over it. I've made another edit in regards to a query example I put inside phpMyAdmin. I hope this helps. Also use `var_dump();` to see what's being passed through your query.

Comment: $Search = pizza is correct. That word resides in title + description + keywords... for example "PIZZA HUT" or DOMINOS PIZZA. The words  "pizzas, restaurant, take away, peperoni" reside in keywords and may also reside in description.... vaya hehe this is making me hungry!!

Comment: @StrayDog Yeah, I'm getting hungry too lol - Now, `AND approved = 'YES'` does play a major role here. All of your columns being cross-queried must also meet that criteria. What happens if you remove that from your query?

Comment: Search by "peperoni" or "take away" does not produce results which is why I am assuming that there is a syntax error in the "$query".... Search by pizza produces results because MOST company names have that word in  TITLE  but not all have that word in TITLE - hence the need to use keywords to find those that do not use the word "pizza" in their TITLE. Vaya hehe this is making me hungry!!

Comment: @StrayDog I'm at a dead end, to be honest with you.

Comment: @StrayDog Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Be cool Fred... you have gone the extra mile and I am truly grateful for your excellent and educated efforts. I wish I could vote you to the top. Anyways... I will plod onward and try to get to the bottom of this... everything has an answer... somewhere!

Comment: @StrayDog *Aye,* that I will ;-) There's always light at the end of the tunnel. Sometimes we just need to go a bit more farther to finally see it, *cheers*

Comment: To all that are helping here you can see a live result of this. I am not sure if Stack Overflow will permit that I add http://eopad.com - I am not trying to abuse this opportunity to win more traffic... to the contrary my website is closed due to this problem. Anyways, although the website is in spanish (I am contracted as a programmer) try this: type "pizza" or "gas" in the search box and you will receive results with the associated keywords echoed in blue in the right hand column. Type a keyword into the search and there are no results although the keywords do exist - weird!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking some time but this is my working answer to my own question... not the prettiest syntax but it works without any string functions or explode functions. MySql can handle keywords quite well without any other functions being included:

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures
WHERE
title LIKE '%$Search%' AND featured IS NOT NULL AND streetview IS NOT NULL AND (id_user > '1') AND (status = '1')
OR
keywords LIKE '%$Search%' AND featured IS NOT NULL AND streetview IS NOT NULL AND (id_user > '1') AND (status = '1') ORDER BY title ASC");

Thank you all for your contributions